# Function compiles under Release Build but not under Debug Build

Tags: c++

Why does this function compile under release build...

```
unsigned int blah()
{

}
```

but not under debug build? It gives an error that says: 'blah': must return a value. What I want to know is the technical reason that this occurs. Why will it accept one but not the other? If it matters, I am using VS2015.

Comment: I'm not sure if the standard mandates it needs to issue a diagnostic here or not.  I can tell you it is undefined behavior.

Comment: It shouldn't compile in either. If it compiles in release, it is probably because the function is being optimized away if you aren't trying to call it.

Comment: Check your release build settings the errors and warning section. I bet they are different from the debug build.

Comment: @CoryKramer - if the function is called, the behavior is undefined. That does not mean that the code shouldn't compile. The C++ language definition only requires a diagnostic here.

Comment: @PeteBecker Correct, but the OP mentioned they were using VS, I just know that happens to be a full-blown compiler error in VS.

Comment: @CoryKramer - then you need to say that. Especially since the code is valid as long as this function isn't called.